# How to share directory alias between user accounts

Tags: sharing, user-account, alias

I'm having trouble using aliases across user accounts.

I have two existing directories:

> `/Users/foo/stuff`
>   `/Users/bar/stuff`

I'd like to alias `/Users/foo/stuff` to be accessible at `/Users/Shared/stuff`.

However, when I try and open the alias as user `bar` it resolves to `/Users/bar/stuff`. I would expect the alias to resolved to the thing it's supposed to be an alias of.

What's going on here? Should I be able to use aliases in this way?

Comment: Works here. What was your method? Simply right click, make alias, move alias to shared? Rename if necessary - not sure from your Q whether you will end up with 2 'stuffs' in shared, one from each user. Also - is 'stuff' a system file, or random other name?

Comment: Yep, that's the method. Strange. More specifically.. "stuff" is `~/Music/iTunes`

Comment: Thought it might have been different for a system folder, but still working here [once i change perms on the original folder to allow the other user access] I get 2 aliases in there, named slightly differently so I know which is which